# how to display the option value in another page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a dropdown box with some name that is selected on one page, and saving correctly in the database. But when i try to edit the page, i get all the values except that dropdown box (that is in the "nothing selected" option) what changes have to be done to my code?
Design code:

```
<option value="select"></option>
<?php foreach ($PName as $row ): ?> 
    <option value="<?=$row['pcode']?>" <?php echo set_select('PName', $row['pcode']); ?>> 
        <?=$row['PName']?></option> 

    <?php endforeach ?>
```

controller code:

```
$query = $this->db->get('parmaster');    
$data['PName']=$query->result_array();
```

Comment: assuming that `PName` field in table has product name and type is String, you should not compare it with $row['pcode'], which assumed to have different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, here the trick is that you must pass the first arguement of set_select() the name of select tag, in your case it is 'PName'

```
    <select id="PName" name="PName">
        <?php 
           foreach ($PName as $row ): 
        ?> 
          <option value="<?=$row['pcode']?>" <?php echo set_select('PName', $row['pcode'], False); ?>> 
                 <?=$row['PName']?>
          </option> 

        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
```

see below codeigniter documentation of set_select() for more help
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=set_select#set_select

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to get all values irrespective of their selection, I would suggest having a hidden field:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="pcodes" value="<?=implode(',',array_column($PName,'pcode'))?>"/>
    <select>...
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
      <option value="">---</option>
 <?php $selected = ($row['pcode'] == your selected data ) ? true : false; ?>
      <?php foreach ($PName as $row ): ?> 
      <option value="<?=$row['pcode']?>" <?php set_select('PName', $row['pcode'], $selected);  ?>> 
                <?=$row['PName']?>
      </option> 
<?php endforeach ?>
```